# CQRS 1st NF Read Model - to what extreme do you allow duplication?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm starting out with my first real CQRS setup. I'm building out the user registration part of the site, the domain and the write side are very familiar to me coming from a standard DDD "style". For the read model I have a denormalizer which handles the AccountCreatedEvent.

For now - for the feature I am implementing, I am only interested in getting users registered. That involves checking uniqueness of email address/username.

So, Say I design a read model specifically for this purpose. an AccountRegistrationReadModel which only holds the parts of the data I'm interested in right now: Username, Email, HashedPassword

Later on, when I start to build up the user profile page, I'm going to need an AccountProfileReadModel.

This read model will share some of the same properties and will have another denormalizer which handles events related to changing profile data, perhaps for instance AccountUsernameChangedEvent

At this point the AccountRegistrationReadModel  and the AccountProfileReadModel are interested in listening to the AccountUsernameChangedEvent messages.

My question is: Is this approach correct? Should i be keeping a read model per feature? Or should I try to normalize it and re-use data, limit duplication where possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think like most design questions, the answer is that it is up to you. Sharing will save computing resources and limit the number of places you have to debug over time. But sharing will also couple things together, potentially unnecessarily, resulting in a different type of cost: brittleness. In a system with a few thousand users and boring queries, a simple and classical user table in a database might do for most of your read models. If you have to scale to huge numbers of users, or a huge number of messages, you'll likely find that some of your other views (audit log? Currently active shipments? Etc) will involve more interesting denormalization or implementation.

Comment: +1 - normalization can lead to brittleness...definitely agree.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @Sebastian said in his answer.  I'd also add that, in my opinion, what the CQRS pattern gives you is the ability to have fast reads at the expense of a slightly slower modification process (because of normalization).  Your reads go against pretty flat data; as a result, you have some duplication in your data store.  But your denormalizers handle keeping that updated.

So, as @Sebastian said, it's up to you.  But the key benefit of moving to CQRS is fast reads and scalability.  If you start normalizing your data and sharing data across models, then you're moving back to a more traditional CRUD application.  At that point, CQRS really isn't helping you -- so there may not be much of a point in using it.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: thank you to both of you for your answers. My feeling is that I'd like a domain model and read model per feature - so a domain & read model for say 'user registration' and a separate domain and read model for say 'user profile page' - is that the right way to go? i'm just worried that i'm breaking it out too much and allowing too much duplication. My argument there is that a user at registration is not the same _thing_ as a user at a profile page - they are separate concerns - is that good thinking or am i talking out my arse?

Comment: Well, I think you'd probably consider a User domain object that eventually feeds into a UserRegistration and UserProfile read models/tables/etc.  The domain object's constructor could very well feed the UserRegistration model, and as the user updates their profile, they call the UpdateUserProfile domain object method which feeds the UserProfile model.  You're not talking out of your arse - but I don't think you'll need a 1:1 relationship b/w domain objects and read models.

Comment: Indeed. Lightly normalized SQL databases really can perform joins awfully quickly and elegantly. For some parts of your read model, this may be totally adequate and easy to implement. You definitely don't need any symmetry between your domain objects and your query model -- indeed allowing you to break them up is the point. For each query you need to do, figure out what the easiest way to do it is. Sometimes you'll find you serve multiple queries off the same view model. Sometimes you'll build a different one. One might be some SQL tables, another might be an in-memory hashtable. Shake well.